# Add Trailing Slash .htaccess failed after several attempts

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I tried almost every solution but not getting success

these are the attempts I tried on htaccess file

1.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

2.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

3.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
 RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

4.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.htm
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Getting Completely Frustrated  ..What can be done more ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
RewriteRule !.+/$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Did you try if .htaccess is used ?  (Add wrong anything to test). And you try to add slash only for directories ?

Comment: My .htaccess  is not refreshing , it i picking up old rewrite rules

Comment: Clear your cache, or try with other browser